# Trying to connect Polybase to Oracle leads to Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication

Tags: sql, polybase, sql-server-2019

I'm using SQL Server 2019 and try to connect to a Oracle DB via Polybase:

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL OracleUser WITH IDENTITY = 'username', Secret = 'password';

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [OrDB] WITH (LOCATION = N'oracle://192.168.1.5:1521'), 
CREDENTIAL = OracleUser);
```

I'm getting the error:

> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication.

However the user is not a domain user and oracle does not use integrated authentication.

Comment: When you execute the code in SQL - are you logged in with Integrated Security? If so, there is a regression issue in SQL which will be fixed. Try and log in with sql server security and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment above, you get this error if you are logged into your SQL Server instance with integrated security. This is due to a regression bug in SQL Server 2019.

Log in with SQL authentication instead, and it will work.

Comment: Hi Niels
The error is gone but now if i try to create the external table i get the following error:
105082;Generic ODBC error: [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver][Oracle]ORA-12660: Encryption or crypto-checksumming parameters incompatible Additional error <2>: ErrorMsg: [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver][Oracle]ORA-12660: Encryption or crypto-checksumming parameters incompatible, SqlState: HY000, NativeError: -1 .

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [OrDB] WITH (LOCATION =     N'oracle://192.168.1.5:1521'), 
CREDENTIAL = OracleUser,
CONNECTION_OPTIONS = 'UseDefaultEncryptionOptions=false'
);
```